# How to call method in method?

Tags: php

I would like to call an other method in from a method in my class, but i don't know how :/

I have an array: ['header', 'navbar', null, 'footer']

I would like to call methods related to string in array

```
public function Render(){
  foreach($array as $v)
    // HERE CALL METHOD ($v) IN MY CLASS ex return: $this->header(), $this->navbar()
}

private function header(){
  //EXEMPLE FESGRDGTFDTHTs
}
private function navbar(){
   //EXEMPLE FESGRDGTFDTHTs
}
```

[ETC]

Ty for community

Comment: Use `$this->$v()`

Answer (score 0):

Just check if provided method exists ([method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)), if so then call it:

```
public function Render(){
    foreach($array as $v)
      if (method_exists($this, $v)) {
        $this->$v();
      }
    }
}
```

Or you can use [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function

```
public function Render() {
    foreach($array as $v) {
        if (method_exists($this, $v)) {
            call_user_func(array($this, $v));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP OOP, you can call a function with `$this->functionName($etc)`. If you have basic knowledge with other programming language (espacially OOP), `$this->` is like `. (dot)` operator.